# How to type hint a class that is inheriting from cached_property?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to create a class that is inheriting from `functools.cached_property` basically to act like `cached_property` but with a different name of the class. The problem is that I can't get it to work with type hinting properly.

This piece of code illustrates what I'm trying to achieve:

```py
from functools import cached_property


class my_property(cached_property):
    
    # without defining __get__ foo attribute below is not even resolved as a property
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return super().__get__(instance, owner)


class Example:
    @my_property
    def foo(self) -> str:
        # some calculations here
        return 'foo'

    @cached_property
    def oof(self) -> str:
        return 'oof'

Example().foo  # foo attribute is resolved as property but of Any type instead of str
Example().oof  # this one is resolved as a property of a str type
```

The issue of the above code is that `foo` attribute is of `Any` type instead of being `str` type. Is there a way to make `my_property` class be resolved in the same way as `cached_property` is?

PS. I'm using VS Code with Pylance extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of struggle I've found the answer using `typing.Generic` that is defined in a class scope like so:

```py
class my_property(cached_property, Generic[T]):

    def __init__(self, func: Callable[[Any], T]) -> T:
        super().__init__(func)

    def __get__(self, instance, owner) -> T:
        return super().__get__(instance, owner)
```

`__init__` method takes a function as an argument, which result is the type that is going to be returned when we access the property. Thus we can define it as a `T` variable in the example above