# mypy for derived class of cached_property

Tags: python, properties, decorator, python-decorators, mypy

When I run mypy check for the following code:

```
from functools import cached_property

def func(s: str) -> None:
    print(s)

class Foo:
    @cached_property
    def prop(self) -> int:
        return 1

foo = Foo()
func(foo.prop)
```

I got error:
`error: Argument 1 to "func" has incompatible type "int"; expected "str"`

Now I want to extend behavior of cached_property for my project by inheriting it:

```
from functools import cached_property

def func(s: str) -> None:
    print(s)

class result_property(cached_property):
    pass

class Foo:
    @result_property
    def prop(self) -> int:
        return 1


foo = Foo()
func(foo.prop)
```

No extra behavior is added to `result_property` yet. But when I run mypy check for it I get:
`Success: no issues found in 1 source file`
I expect the result of type check should by the same in both cases. Why is it different?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/73896929/1126841

Answer (score 0):

Mypy handles inheritance and type inference with decorators differently, which is probably the reason for the variation in behaviour between your two cases. Mypy can accurately determine the type of the property when you use the normal cached_property decorator. Nevertheless, mypy might not carry out the same degree of type inference when you construct a subclass of cached_property, such as result_property, unless you explicitly state the types or make use of extra typing hints.

You can utilise Python's typing facilities to make corrections to the code and guarantee that, when using a custom decorator, mypy correctly infers the type of the property. You must specifically define your custom ***result_property*** as a generic class and make sure that, in terms of type annotations, it accurately emulates the behaviour of ***cached_property***. Here's an illustration of how to accomplish it:

```
from functools import cached_property
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, Callable, Any

T = TypeVar('T')

class result_property(Generic[T], cached_property):
    def __init__(self, func: Callable[..., T]) -> None:
        super().__init__(func)

def func(s: str) -> None:
    print(s)

class Foo:
    @result_property
    def prop(self) -> int:
        return 1

foo = Foo()
func(foo.prop)  # This should still raise a mypy error
```

This code defines a generic class called result_property, which extends cached_property. This aids in mypy's comprehension of the style of the furnished property. Now that the sample properly recognises the type of foo.prop as int and uses cached_property, it ought to return the same mypy error as your original code.